# Why does "vagrant ssh" work, but PHPStorm 9's "start SSH session" doesn't?

Tags: macos, ssh, vagrant, phpstorm

I'm trying to ssh into a Vagrant box inside Mac OSX using PHPStorm 9. It works perfectly from the Terminal or from the command line inside PHPStorm, but PHPStorm's native "Tools -> Start SSH session..." (which should basically do exactly the same: calling "vagrant ssh") does absolutly nothing (no feedback, nothing happens, nothing opens).

**Question:** Is this a common issue, is something missing, do I have to do some weird configs before ?

Answer (score 4):

This likely happens because PHP Storm is using your default ssh key where it should use the *insecure_private_key* key from vagrant:

```
~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

You can either copy your personal public key to the vagrant box

```
ssh-copy-id -p 2222 vagrant@localhost
```

(password: vagrant), or (preferred) configure PHPStorm that it uses the vagrant key, like:

```
ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key localhost -p 2222
```

---

Note that I'm using the default forwarded ssh port number 2222, if you are not using this port, pass the port number you are actually using.

Comment: How to 'configure PHPStorm that it uses the vagrant key' ?

Comment: Unf. I'm not using phpstorm. Probably you may me able to enter the ssh options somewhere?